# Laravel 8 Jetstream custom api

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I'm attempting to create a login endpoint so that I can use it without a blade.php file. While working with Unreal engine I cant use a actual web page so wanting to create a Login endpoint that will send back custom json. The below is what I have set up. When i use postman or Python requests I get a page response of Not Found or page expired. How can I get this to return the test or failed?

api.php

```
Route::post('/unreal-login', 'App\Http\Controllers\UnrealLoginController@authenticate');
```

UnrealLoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UnrealLoginController extends Controller{
    public function authenticate(Request $request){
        // Retrive Input
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // if success login

            return "test";

            //return redirect()->intended('/details');
        }
        // if failed login
        return "failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: you need token based auth system  i guess